# Use Model Property in a Django Model Form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am attempting to use model properties like fields within a model form, but so far haven't had any luck. The result is that the form renders only the model fields, and not the property I defined. Any idea how to get the form to recognize the property added to the model? I expect to see the latitude property added as just another field in the form.

**Models.py:**

```
class Plot(models.Model):
        plot_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        plot_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], null=False, unique=True)
        geometry = models.PointField(srid=2163, null=True, blank=True) 
        objects = models.GeoManager()

        @property
        def latitude(self):
            self.geometry.transform(4326)
            return self.geometry.y

        @latitude.setter
        def latitude(self, latitude):
            self.geometry.y = latitude
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class InventoryPlotForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ForestInventoryPlot
        exclude = {"geometry"}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but note that `exclude = {"geometry"}` defines a `set`, which is not _technically_ a wrong value for the `Meta.exclude` attribute, but kind-of weird and unexpected.

Comment: I simplified the forms and model to make my point more clear. In doing so, I didn't catch that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Have a look at GeoDjango's [forms api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api) which provides fields that you can use. Since its a property, you need to create your own field for it.

Comment: Burhan, the field I am creating isn't a point geometry once I've split the geometry field in latitude.  At that  point the ordinate is simply a decimal so I don't believe the pointfield will help me. You're right about the need to create a new field for the form though, thanks for the post.

Answer (score 5):

Some years later. A complete answer, working in Django up to 2.2. As others have pointed out, only real db fields are included in the model form. So, you'll need to:

- Define a custom model form, add your @property field
- Exclude your geometry field
- In the `__init__` of the form, get the value, and set it as `initial`.
- Customize your save method (on the form or admin)

Note: This works also in more complex cases, where you want to abstract away some more complex database structure...

```
class InventoryPlotForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ForestInventoryPlot
        exclude = ("geometry", )

    latitude = forms.WhateverField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if instance:
            kwargs['initial'] = {'latitude': instance.latitude, }
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.latitude = self.cleaned_data['latitude']
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You are the best! Just a detail: __init__ does not return anything, so last line of it would be just super().__init__(*args, **kwargs). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Only Django Fields are automatically generated by ModelForm.

- You need to define your field in the ModelForm
- Probably make geometry field hidden
- Write custom ModelForm Save method and separately save model fields and model properties.
- Modify your view to set the initial for the ModelForm

For example something like this:

```
class InventoryPlotForm(ModelForm):
    latitude = forms.CharField(max_length=52)           # Something like this

    def save(self, commit=True):
        model_instance = super(InventoryPlotForm, self).save(commit=False)
        result = super(InventoryPlotForm, self).save(commit=True)
        model_instance.latitude = self.cleaned_data['latitude']
        model_instance.save()
        return result

    class Meta:
        model = ForestInventoryPlot
        widgets = {'geometry': HiddenInput()}
```

in your view

```
...
form = InventoryPlotForm(instance=forestinventoryplot,
                         initial={"latitude":forestinventoryplot.latitude})
...
```

Comment: I implemented essentially what you have here and added the latitude form field, but I get the error type object 'InventoryPlotForm' has no attribute 'latitude'. Thanks for the example it helps greatly, I will have to tinker a bit and check back in.

Comment: This is very handy, but any idea why super.save() is called twice?

Answer (score 2):

Your property is not a `Field` instance, and as such a `ModelForm` cannot automatically generate a form field for it. You will need to explicitly define a `latitude` field on the `InventoryPlotForm` and manage its retrieval and update in the form's `__init__` and `save` methods. Alternatively, you can implement your own `Widget` class and tell your `InventoryPlotForm` to use it for the `geometry` field:

```
class InventoryPlotForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        widgets = {
            'geometry': MyGeometryWidget,
        }
        ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Lanzz, I've considered going the widget route, but I decided that using a property to handle this situation would be a good approach, mostly because I thought integration into the form would be trivial. Maybe I will reconsider, since the widget would be reusable in other models. Conceptually I understand that, as you said, I need to create a form field and then handle the retrieval and update of that field, but I am having difficulty implementing that. Let me bang around  a while and see if I can't figure it out.